# Vue3 await for Pinia data

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vue-suspense

I'm trying to use `Suspense` to show a loading spinner. It works fine when using with `fetch` directly. However in some cases it doesn't work since I need to await for data already being fetched from another component.

```
Navbar --> userStore.fetchUser()
Main --> await userStore.user
```

App.vue:

```js
<template>
  <header>
    <!-- this fetches user -->
    <Nav />
  </header>

  <div>
    <Suspense>
      <!-- I need to await inside this component -->
      <RouterView />
      <template #fallback>
        LOADING...
      </template>
    </Suspense>
  </div>
</template>
```

I assume this doesn't work since the `Suspense` is bit wrapping the Nav. But how can I achieve this since I want the nav to always be visible? And the data needs to be fetched inside Nav to show the user's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this the old school way without `Suspense`. Just set a variable `userInitated: false` in your store, which you set to `true` after the user is successfully fetched in the `userStore.fetchUser` function.

In your template you can set something like:

```
<div>
   <template v-if="userStore.userInitiated">
      <RouterView/>
   </template>
   <template v-else>
      LOADING... 
   </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing in the end. Seems all the bells & whistles added in Vue3 just overcomplicate everything.

Comment: I agree. Suspense seems just too fragile, while I think this solution is quite elegant since the working and purpose are immediately clear.